# Is there Opensource code for parsing SQL Server Proc?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm looking at writing a tool for generating code based on the contents of a stored procedure.  Like the parameters and stuff.

I was wondering if anybody knew of an open source library that has a all the regex's and stuff to parse all this easily.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the proc is already in Sql Server, and you're just looking for parameter info, you can query [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173796.aspx). Also, [sp_help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187335(SQL.90).aspx) will show it as the second resultset.

Answer (score 0):

try [GOLD parser](http://www.devincook.com/goldparser/)